# Multiline log statement with indent

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog and I want to format multi-line log messages with indention to appear in the log file like this:

```
2023-10-06 09:15:50.1069 DEBUG  MessagePublisher Published Message:
                                Id: fb7AHbKq
                                Key: SomeKey
                                State: Set
```

The message already contains line breaks which were added during the `ToString` call of my object. Therefor the string hand over to NLog looks like this:

```
MessagePublisher Published Message:
Id: fb7AHbKq
Key: SomeKey
State: Set
```

My NLog layout config currently looks like this:

```xml
    <variable name="formattedMessage"
              value="${replace-newlines:replacement=\n                :${message}${onexception:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}}" />

    <variable name="header" value="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd} ${time} ${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5}  ${logger:shortName=true}" />

    <target layout="${header} ${formattedMessage}" />
```

But this does not work reliably on all machines. Sometimes the indention is broken and the log file looks like this:

```
2023-10-06 09:15:50.1069 DEBUG  MessagePublisher Published Message:
                Id: fb7AHbKq
                Key: SomeKey
                State: Set
```

I am not sure why the spaces are duplicated under some circumstances. I have also tried to do it with the padding functionality but that didn't work either.

How is it supposed to be done right?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The symptom of variant spacing between machines is likely related to the display font. Some fonts use varying width characters, so the use of spaces as you have in your formatter will use a different amount of space on screen. It's probably safer to use tabs ```\t``` instead of spaces, but even this will have variations. I would first ensure those different machines use the same font in the application you use to open the log. It could be whether ClearType is enabled on Windows. On Apple devices "Use LCD font smoothing when available" in General options of System Preferences  my have an effect

Comment: Thank you for the hint - I didn't know about that and I will check that.